# How to leave a gap between two objects [Illustrator]

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

So for a while now I've been wondering how to put a gap between two objects like in the example given. [image: As you can see here],
, between the wings and shield, there is an even gap.
Is there a short cut or do I have to go in and move each point individually? its a bit frustrating

Comment: Its just a stroke?

Comment: It might be, but I was wondering if there was a way to make that spot transparent

Comment: Strokes can be expanded, as explained below. You can also make strokes transparent but still carving out shape from the local group. Thisway you can change the thickness on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the front object.
2. Copy cmd+c
3. Paste in Back cmd+B
4. Add a stoke and set it to the width you want the gap to be.
5. Expand the object with the stroke: Object > Expand...

   - make sure all 3 boxes are checked "object, stroke and fill"
6. In the pathfinder pallet click on the combine objects icon (first one on the top row)
7. Now hold shift and click on the object in back.
8. With both selected click the "minus front" icon in the pathfinder pallet. (second icon on the top row)
9. The front shape plus the stroke have now been cut out of the back object.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this:

1. Select the front object
2. Use the Object-->Path-->Offset path and input the width of the gap you want.
3. You will be left with two paths, the original one and a larger one. Select the larger one and the back object
4. Use the "minus front" option in the Pathfinder palette

Comment: I think this is better than my answer.. simpler. Good idea. I have always used the stroke method because it is how I first figured it out. Not sure why it never clicked to use offset path. Thx for adding this.